# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (mongoDB + ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, jsonp, mongodb-rest

I'm using following code to get the response from MongoDB rest service. But It gives error

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

I have enabled rest service in MongoDB using command

```
mongod  --rest  --jsonp
```

Following is code for ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',    
      url: "myDB/myCollection/",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true, 
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
```

This is a data return by rest service :

```
{
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57173811e28098f50d3e065a" }, "name" : "abc" } ,
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57173821e28098f50d3e065c" }, "name" : "xyz" }
  ],
  "total_rows" : 2 ,
  "query" : {} ,
  "millis" : 0
}
```

Please help me to get data from MongoDB rest service using ajax call.

Comment: shouldn't you use `dataType: "json"`, instead of `jsonp`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing to enable httpinterface. Enable it using following command

`mongod --httpinterface`